# Parse Excel formula string into preceding string, the function, arguments, and post function string in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, parsing

For a given Excel function (e.g. `VLOOKUP`), I need to parse a cell's formula string into:

- `preFunctionStr` = The string preceding the VLOOKUP function
- `ExcelFn` = "VLOOKUP"
- `Arguments` = Collection of all the arguments within the VLOOKUP function (which themselves could contain functions)
- `postFunctionStr` = The string following the last ")" in the formula string

My main reason for wanting this is to be able to convert Excel formulae without changing their answer. For example, convert `SUMIF` into `SUMIFS` and convert `VLOOKUP` into a combination of `INDEX` and `MATCH`.

In my example, I am in a cell that contains the formula `=A4+VLOOKUP(2,$E$4:$F$8,MATCH("Value(1)",$E$4:$F$4,0),0) + 2000` which I need to parse into the components described above.

Although I could find plenty of material on parsing Excel formulae, I couldn't find one that breaks it into these components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my solution, I create a `Class module` with the properties I require a formula string to be split into called `ExcelFormulaParser`:

```
Option Explicit

Public ExcelFn As String
Public Arguments As New Collection
Public preFunctionStr As String
Public postFunctionStr As String

Sub SetMeUp(formulaStr As String, FormulaToParse As String)

    Dim FormulaStartPos As Integer
    Dim OpenBracketCounter As Integer
    Dim OpenBracketCount As Integer
    Dim ClosedBracketCount As Integer
    Dim WithinQuote As Boolean
        ' whether we are within quotation marks
    Dim i As Integer

    Dim strChr As String
    Dim Arg_i As String
    Dim Arg As String

    Me.ExcelFn = FormulaToParse

    FormulaStartPos = InStr(1, formulaStr, FormulaToParse)

    Me.preFunctionStr = Mid(formulaStr, 1, FormulaStartPos - 1)
    formulaStr = Mid(formulaStr, FormulaStartPos + Len(FormulaToParse), Len(formulaStr) - Len(FormulaToParse))

    If Left(formulaStr, 1) = "(" Then
        OpenBracketCounter = 1
        formulaStr = Mid(formulaStr, 2, Len(formulaStr) - 1)
    Else
        MsgBox ("Not the full FormulaToParse")
        End
    End If

    i = 0
    Arg_i = ""
    Do While OpenBracketCounter > 0
        i = i + 1
        strChr = Left(formulaStr, 1)
        If Len(formulaStr) > 0 Then
            formulaStr = Right(formulaStr, Len(formulaStr) - 1)
        End If

        If strChr = Chr(34) Then
            WithinQuote = Not (WithinQuote) ' toggle WithinQuote on or off
            ' don't count brackets within quotation marks
        ElseIf strChr = "(" And WithinQuote = False Then
            OpenBracketCounter = OpenBracketCounter + 1
        ElseIf strChr = ")" And WithinQuote = False Then
            OpenBracketCounter = OpenBracketCounter - 1
        End If

        If OpenBracketCounter = 1 And strChr = "," Then
            Arg = Arg_i
            Me.Arguments.Add Arg
            Arg_i = ""
        ElseIf OpenBracketCounter = 0 Then
            Arg = Arg_i
            Me.Arguments.Add Arg
            Arg_i = ""
            Me.postFunctionStr = formulaStr
        Else
            Arg_i = Arg_i & strChr
        End If
    Loop

End Sub
```

To provide an example of how to call and use the `Class module`, I created the following Module within the same VBA Project:

```
Sub TestFormulaParser()

    Dim ParsedForm As ExcelFormulaParser
    Set ParsedForm = New ExcelFormulaParser
    Dim StrToParse As String
    StrToParse = ActiveCell.Formula
        ' formula contains:
        '' =A4+VLOOKUP(2,$E$4:$F$8,MATCH("Value(1)",$E$4:$F$4,0),0) + 2000
    Call ParsedForm.SetMeUp(StrToParse, "VLOOKUP")

    preFunctionStr = ParsedForm.preFunctionStr
        ' returns the prefunction string i.e. =A4+
    ExcelFn = ParsedForm.ExcelFn
        ' returns the excel function we parsed i.e. VLOOKUP
    Arg1 = ParsedForm.Arguments(1)
        ' returns the first argument of the VLOOKUP function i.e. 2
    Arg2 = ParsedForm.Arguments(2)
        ' returns the second argument of the VLOOKUP function i.e. $E$4:$F$8
    Arg3 = ParsedForm.Arguments(3)
        ' returns the third argument of the VLOOKUP function i.e. MATCH("Value(1)",$E$4:$F$4,0)
    Arg4 = ParsedForm.Arguments(4)
        ' returns the fourth argument of the VLOOKUP function i.e. 0
    postFunctionStr = ParsedForm.postFunctionStr
        ' returns the post function string i.e.  + 2000

End Sub
```

Comment: so you find a solution for your problem or is there some remaining issues ? if yes which ones ?

Comment: @h2so4 I am happy with my solution and wanted to share that to the community (given I couldn't find another solution online). If other can improve on this it would also be great (for example, it might be cleaner if you don't need to use a `class module`?